# SQL plus running multiple queries

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I have 12 queries to run, but can not run at the same time. I would like to start the first query, then as soon as it completes the next query begins, when it completes the third query starts and so on. Want this to be automatic. Each query writes a txt file. Thanks

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you have any issues running anything in the current format you have? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me like you just have to create a script and call that script:

```
@query1.sql
@query2.sql
...
```

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Paste them all in 1 file with a GO statement between should do the trick.